# xa-datasource in wildfly 14 looking for db2jcct2 instead of db2jcc4

Tags: java, jboss, db2, wildfly

Wildfly 14 Server is running with a lot of working datasource.
db2jcc4.jar is in the module directory and is working with other datasources.
Now, I have to add a new datasource to another DB2 Database with SSL support.
If I add this new datasource and use it through application, then there is an Exception:

> Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db2jcct2 in java.library.path

It seems the driver is looking for the wrong native module db2jcct2 instead of db2jcc (Type 2 instead of Type 4).
I tried two ways:

```
<xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:db2://servername:port/dbname:sslConnection=true;;</xa-datasource-property>
```

And also:

```
<xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
    servername
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
    port
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
    dbname
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="currentSQLID">
    sqlid
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="driverType">
    4
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="deferPrepares">
    false
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="Ssl">
    true
</xa-datasource-property>
<driver>db2stat</driver>
```

And some other common properties for the datasource:

```
<xa-pool>
    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
</xa-pool>
<security>
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
</security>
<recovery>
    <recover-plugin class-name="org.jboss.jca.core.recovery.ConfigurableRecoveryPlugin"/>
    </recovery>
    <validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2StaleConnectionChecker"/>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
<statement>
    <track-statements>nowarn</track-statements>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>30</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
</statement>
```

It seems the problem occures after activation ssl.
Anybody an idea?